# Latitudes and Longitudes in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, latitude-longitude

I have an earth model and I want an object to move according to the latitudes and longitudes on the model. I have the formula for converting lats and longs to ECEF XYZ but it exceeds the floating -point precision in unity and my model is pretty small. I am using it because I wanted an offline map. Anyways, I am using this formula, I tried changing the radius to my model radius but it does not work

```
public const float EarthRadius = 6,371f;
{
    float cosLat = Mathf.Cos(latitude * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    float sinLat = Mathf.Sin(latitude * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    float cosLon = Mathf.Cos(longitude * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    float sinLon = Mathf.Sin(longitude * Mathf.Deg2Rad);

    float radius = EarthRadius / Mathf.Sqrt(1.0f - 0.00669437999014f * sinLat * sinLon);

    float x = (radius + altitude) * cosLat * cosLon;
    float y = (radius + altitude) * cosLat * sinLon;
    float z = (radius * (1.0f - 0.00669437999014f) + altitude) * sinLat;

    return new Vector3(x, y, z);

}
```

How can I solve this conversion to get correct coordinates? It does not have to be precise. I just want my object to move to that latitudes and longitudes.

Comment: I am a little confused by your question. What exactly is the problem you are having? Is it with the calculation? In the code you provided, how are latitude and longitude defined? Could you also quote the exact error you are getting?